# Get Network statistic for Client Apps in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, networking, counter

I was looking into network statistics in powershell and there are a lot of good scripts to measure:

- Network traffic through a network card using counter
- List all connections using for example windows built in functions

What I am looking for is the detailed info about the network traffic per client connection, so how how much traffic (bytes sent\read) is consumed by the remote client application.

Any suggestions how to start ?

Answer (score 0):

I think [TCPView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) by Sysinternals should do the trick. This gives you real-time traffic on a per process level.

You would filter by the process or remote address or source port, depending on what the Client App in question is, and then you would see sent and received packets and bytes for each TCP/UDP connection.